# Validate ASP.NET Webforms with AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, validation, webforms

To use AngularJS validation status I need to reference the form by its name. However the form that I have does not have a name, and I have no idea how to set a name, other than using Javascript, which I don't want to do. When I add the `name` attribute to the `<form runat="server">` it doesn't appear in the output HTML.

Example of how it would be ideal to work:

```
<form name="form">
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtl">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required><br>
        <span ng-show="form.firstName.$dirty">Dirty</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

A solution would be either of these two:

- Reference the form elements by ID instead of name
- Get ASP.NET webforms to output the `name` attribute

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET controls have been modified in the .NET Framework version 4.](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770141)

The HtmlForm control does not render a name attribute anymore.

To disable the new rendering mode, add the following setting in the Web.config file:

```
  <system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute to a web forms control from the code behind using:

```
controlName.Attributes.Add("name","value");

<asp:TextBox ID="controlName" runat="server"/>
```

Or if you want to use Ids with .NET 4 you can set the attribute ClientIDMode eg

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="controlName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

then you can reference it by ID

HTH

Comment: yes, that's pretty obvious, but how do you set the `name` attribute on the form element?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery to modify the form tag

$('#form').attr('name', 'form');